# Open-sesame UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2779: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, open-sesame

I'm trying to train open-sesame model following https://github.com/swabhs/open-sesame instructions. Here the issue:

```
(test-pip-install) C:\Users\GAIA\open-sesame>python -m sesame.targetid --mode train --model_name fn1.7-pretrained-targetid
```

When i launch the command above, then it returns these errors:

```
Reading pretrained embeddings from data/glove.6B.100d.txt ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GAIA\Miniconda3\envs\test-pip-install\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\GAIA\Miniconda3\envs\test-pip-install\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\GAIA\open-sesame\sesame\targetid.py", line 95, in <module>
    pretrained_map = get_wvec_map()
  File "C:\Users\GAIA\open-sesame\sesame\dataio.py", line 309, in get_wvec_map
    [float(f) for f in line.strip().split(' ')[1:]] for line in wvf}
  File "C:\Users\GAIA\open-sesame\sesame\dataio.py", line 308, in <dictcomp>
    wd_vecs = {VOCDICT.addstr(line.split(' ')[0]) :
  File "C:\Users\GAIA\Miniconda3\envs\test-pip-install\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2779: character maps to <undefined>
```